# Probability of finding a lost ball

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

From a box with m white and n black balls, a ball has been lost. In order to figure out the content of the box, two balls have been taken from it. Both balls were white. Find the probability that the lost ball was white.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question, since the process by which the ball was lost is not known. Was the lost ball uniformly randomly chosen from the $m+n$ balls? Did a badger who likes to munch on white balls come and steal a ball?

Comment: The task is taken from a book, and it says that from a box with m white and n black balls one has been lost. It means a random ball was lost from the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pedestrian way:

\begin{align}
P(\text{white lost})&=\frac m{m+n}\;,\\
P(\text{both white})&=\frac{\binom m2}{\binom{m+n}2}\;,\\
P(\text{both white}\mid\text{white lost})&=\frac{\binom{m-1}2}{\binom{m+n-1}2}\;.
\end{align}

Thus

\begin{align}
P(\text{white lost}\mid\text{both white})&=\frac{P(\text{both white}\mid\text{white lost})\,P(\text{white lost})}{P(\text{both white})}\\
&=\frac{\binom{m-1}2\binom{m+n}2}{\binom m2\binom{m+n-1}2}\frac m{m+n}\\
&=\frac{(m-2)(m+n)}{m(m+n-2)}\frac m{m+n}\\
&=\frac{m-2}{m+n-2}\;.
\end{align}

The more elegant way:

Two white balls are known not to be lost. All other balls have the same probability of being lost.

Comment: The amount of black balls could be bigger than the amount of white balls, doesn't this mean that the probability of losing a black ball is bigger?

Comment: @Hydroxis: Sure it does -- how does that contradict anything in the answer?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the elegant way.

Comment: @Hydroxis: There are $m+n$ balls, of which $m$ are white. Our information is that two particular white balls weren't lost; we don't know anything about the remaining balls, so each of them is equally likely to have been lost. There are $m+n-2$ remaining balls, and $m-2$ of them are white.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your solution is wrong. You did not account the fact that a black ball might've been lost. This is a simple matter of applying bayes's fomula.

Comment: @kjanko: Perhaps it escaped your attention that I did apply Bayes' theorem. I also provided a second route to the same answer. It's hard to comment on the fact that you get a different answer unless you show us how. It's not clear to me why you think I didn't account for the fact that a black ball might have been lost -- I would have thought that not accounting for this possibility would lead to a probabilty $1$ of a while ball having been lost.

Comment: $A$: a white ball was lost

$B$: a black ball was losts

$P(A) = m/m+n$

$P(B) = n/m+n$

$C$: two white balls have been extracted

$P(C|A) = C(m-1, 2)/C(m+n-1, 2)$

$P(C|B) = C(m, 2)/C(m+n-1, 2)$

$P(A)$ - apply Bayes's theorem

Comment: @kjanko: I don't see why that way of appliying Bayes' theorem would seem preferable to you to how I applied it; perpaps that's a matter of subjective preference. Do we at least agree that the result is the same and both derivations are correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is an explanation for the "more elegant way" mentioned in joriki's answer.

There are $(m+n-2)$ balls remaining (including the lost one) after removing the two white balls.

The probability of any one of these balls being the lost ball is the same:  $1/(m+n-2)$.

There are $(m-2)$ white balls remaining in this group, which gives the answer.